# Fourier Transform of $(2H(x)-1)\cdot\delta(2H(x)-2)$

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am trying to calculate the Fourier transform of of the function (distribution):
\begin{cases}
              \delta(x-1) & x>0, \\
             -\delta(-x-1) & x<0.
\end{cases}
I tried to rewrite it as
$$\begin{align}
& \operatorname{sign}(x)\cdot\delta(\operatorname{sign}(x)-1) = \\
&(2H(x)-1)\cdot\delta(2H(x)-2)
\end{align} $$
but I do not se where to take it from here. Does it even make sense to use the Fourier transform on such a function? The Laplace transform would also be of some intrest to me. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Your distribution is just two Dirac peaks at $1$ and $-1$, ie. you need to find $c$ such that $f = \delta(x-1)+c\,\delta(x+1)$ whose Fourier and Laplace transform is easy.

Comment: @reuns So basically it's just $f=\delta(x-1)-\delta(x+1)$, correct?